# Linux - run dialog script in background

Tags: bash, background, dialog

I try to run in background a dialog bash script. The script is called dialog_localscript and I'm try to launch it with the command:
./dialog_localscript.sh &

If I run it not in background it correctly works. If I run it with '&' it works as continously "enter" Keys is pressed: it continously process "enter" input.

I tried to launch in background also dialog examples located in /usr/share/doc/dialog/examples and I observed the same problem.

Is there a way to run dialog bash script in background without problem?

Comment: What is a "dialog bash script"?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bash script which use dialog (http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_dialog.php) to display interface.